# InnoDB -> Number of keys for Int vs VarChar

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

I was reading through various forums and stack over flow questions but couldn't find my answer.

I'm trying to find out the number of keys which will be stored in 16KB InnoDb Database page.

As you can see in [this forum](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?21,36252,36263) they mentioned how to calculate the number of keys for MyISAM in a single page . I would like to do the same for InnoDb. I don't understand how these calculations were made.

Im comparing a int which is 4KB and a VARCHAR (200). It would be great if I can get this calculation.

Answer (score 0):

- An index is structured as a BTree.
- InnoDB BTrees are initially filled only 15/16th full.
- After a lot of churn, a BTree averages 69% full.
- There is a significant amount of overhead for each 'row' in a index entry.
- The `PRIMARY KEY` (in InnoDB) is "clustered" with the data.  So only the non-leaf nodes take extra blocks.
- Secondary indexes contain all the column(s) of the `PRIMARY KEY`; that is how they 'point' to the record.
- Based on the above two items, it is not meaningful to have just an `INT` in an the BTree for an index.

I use the simple Rule of Thumb:  100 'rows' per BTree.
Corollary:  A million-row BTree is about 3 levels deep; a billion-row table is about 5 level deep.

Let's take this:

```
CREATE TABLE x (
    id INT ...,
    num INT ...,
    str VARCHAR(200) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    INDEX i_num (num),
    INDEX i_str (str)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

For `i_num`, note that there are two `INTs`.  You might get 300-400 'rows' per block.  10 million rows would take 3 levels.

For `i_str`, let's assume an average of 100 Korean characters -- that's 300 bytes for the text.  You might get 25-35 'rows' per block.  10M rows would take 5 levels.

`ALTER` and `OPTIMIZE` may *or may not* defragment indexes.

There are `information_schema` tables that give *some* details about each BTree and its levels.  Percona and MySQL have different tables for such.

Bottom line:  The computations are too fuzzy to be exact.  I hope my hand-waving has given you some better handles.